# Initialize size of char in struct depending on file reading conditions

Tags: c++, global-variables, constants

I would like to initialize this :

toto.cpp

```
typedef struct {
  ...
  unsigned char au8FrameBuffer[FRAME_SIZE]; 
  ...
}tstrFrameRawData;
```

But the frame size depends on the configuration written in a file.

main.cpp

```
string cameraSource = configFile.getItem("CAMERA_SOURCE");
if (cameraSource == "CAMERA_WGA")
          {
                frameFormat = FDESC_u8FORMAT_GRAY_8BIT_752_480;
                frameWidth = 752;
                frameHeight = 480;
```

`FRAME_SIZE` is `frameWidth*frameHeight`, those are global variables.

But since `unsigned char au8FrameBuffer[FRAME_SIZE]` is waiting for a constant FRAME_SIZE I don't know how to pass it.

Comment: Make `au8FrameBuffer` a char pointer and then, after reading the config file, point to the allocated `char[FRAME_SIZE]`

Comment: Since you are using a static array its size has to be known at compile time. You could instead use a character pointer in the structure and dynamically create the array on the heap after you calculated its size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a character pointer in the structure and dynamically create the array on the heap after you calculated its size.

```
 typedef struct {
  ...
  unsigned char* au8FrameBuffer; 
  ...
}tstrFrameRawData;

....

FRAME_SIZE=frameWidth*frameHeight;
tstrFrameRawData.au8FrameBuffer=new unsigned char[FRAME_SIZE];//dynamically created the array

 ....
//delete[] tstrFrameRawData.au8FrameBuffer;//delete it once you are done
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a char array, use a `std::vector<char>` which you can set to the right size with a constructor call, or with `resize`.  When you need a pointer use `&buf[0]`